# Missing dates when exporting outlook calendar

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2003, export

When exporting an outlook 2003 Calendar to CVS, excel, or access recurring appointments that I have changed the start time on are not included in the exported appointments.

Example I have an appointment every other Friday from 8 - 12 that I set up as a recurrence. I then changed the start time on several occurrences.

None of the appointments with the changed time are exported.

How do I export ALL the appointments?

Answer (score 1):

Any chance this is the issue?

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HP052426661033.aspx

> Only one of my recurring tasks or
>   appointments is displayed.
>
> If you export a recurring task or
>   appointment from a Personal Folders
>   file (.pst) stored on your hard disk,
>   only the first occurrence is exported.
>   Make copies of the tasks or
>   appointments and change the dates.

Comment: The appointment is not coming from a personal folder, it's on my regular calendar. All of them are exporting with the exception that the ones I changed the start time on.